# SMARTS: recursive search

Tags: computational-chemistry

i have a question regarding the usage of recursive SMARTS. I'm using python and rdkit for my coding. My goal is to get the substructure of carboxylic acids which are bonded by an ethyl-group to an aromatic compound. So far so good. With the following script I'm only getting substructure hits for methyl-linkers, although I'm defining an ethyl linker (CCa) . I mean i get my desired outcome by just adding another "C" but i still wanna understand the problem.

```
smiles_list = ["OC(CCCC1=CC=CC=C1)=O", "OC(CCC1=CC=CC=C1)=O", "OC(CC1=CC=CC=C1)=O", "OC(C1=CC=CC=C1)=O"]
mols = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles) for smiles in smiles_list]
smarts_carboxy= "[C$(CCa)](=O)[OX2H1]"
patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts(smarts_carboxy)
highlight_scaffold = [mol.GetSubstructMatch(patt) for mol in mols]

Draw.MolsToGridImage(mols, highlightAtomLists = highlight_scaffold, molsPerRow=5, subImgSize=(300,300))
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[C$(CCa)]` means that you are looking for a carbon and the found carbon is bonded to a carbon that is bonded to an aromatic atom.

The recursive part starts always with the atom you are looking for and is followed by a condition, so there is only one carbon in the linker.

Adding another `C` sets the conditon to two carbons.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer! From time to time SMARTS can be a bit confusing....